# Cache Lazy Collection in Hibernate second level cache on jboss WildFly

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Is it possible to cache lazily collections in hibernate cache?

Environment: Jboss wildfly, jpa 2, jpa provider hibernate 4.3.1

persistence.xml contains:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Actor extends BaseEntity implements NamedEntity, GatheredEntity {

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
private Set<Movie> movies;
```

First Access over a HQL-Query work.

```
[org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] (default task-1) Session Metrics {
    934038 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    411968 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
    2206400 nanoseconds spent preparing 11 JDBC statements;
    26865079 nanoseconds spent executing 11 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    49744275 nanoseconds spent performing 182 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    784562 nanoseconds spent performing 10 L2C misses;
    65398339 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 182 entities and 299 collections);
    70728 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Second access produces:

```
[org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] (default task-10) Session Metrics {
    0 nanoseconds spent acquiring 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    3523604 nanoseconds spent performing 123 L2C hits;
    84581 nanoseconds spent performing 4 L2C misses;
    42442586 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 122 entities and 244 collections);
    4740 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Query is cached. But member access produces:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Actor.movies, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

thats sounds that the member "movies" is not cached in l2c because it is a lazily initalized collection.

I have tried following annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Actor extends BaseEntity implements NamedEntity, GatheredEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private Set<Movie> movies;
```

But wildfly doesn't start:

```
9:07:39,115 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "moviedatabase.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"moviedatabase.war#"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"moviedatabase.war": org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath."}}
```

I have tried several for hours to set hibernate.cache.region.factory_class for infispan an wildfly. But I had no luck.
Ay ideas to cache lazily collections in l2c with access over hql.

Comment: In `persistence.xml`: `<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory"/>`. I have the same issue and have taken the same approach but collection information still not cached. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @chrisjleu Did you find a solution?